# How would you measure current energy/battery usage?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I try to create applications that can prove how coding and chosen techniqies can improve (respectively worsen) the energy consumption. How would you do and what libraries to use in Windows Store applications, to measure the current usage of power / key number for energy consumption?

I know about applications that measure the amount that apps are consuming, but I would like to have it inside the application. The possibilities to have it presented and perhaps more verbose is really helpfull here.

(I assume that I must adress a specific technique to avoid being to broad)

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't specified your language, I'll assume that you code in c# because it's the most used language on WinRT. However the following class also exists in VB.NET and in C++ under the same namespace.

This is pretty much everything you can do with this class:

```
using Windows.Phone.Devices.Power;

protected void Foo() {
    var b = Battery.GetDefault();
    var chargeLeft = b.RemainingChargePercent;
    var timeLeft = b.RemainingDischargeTime;
    b.RemainingChargePercentChanged += B_RemainingChargePercentChanged; 
}

private void B_RemainingChargePercentChanged(object sender, object e) {
    // To do... 
}
```

Determining the power consumption speed is pretty much straightforward from then, since it's the derivative of the charge by the time.